# Count number of duplicate rows, sort from most to least (statistic)

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I'm trying to make statistic of top-10 most visited URL. I have one simple table. For each URL visit, one row added with that URL as content. Most visited URL has the most number of duplicate.

I've found many reference to `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename WHERE url='tofind'` but that only works if I supply the URL data.

Suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried something like SELECT COUNT(url) AS My_Count FROM tablename ORDER BY My_Count DESC LIMIT 10? You might need to change the position of LIMIT 10.

Comment: @Vérace you also need `GROUP BY url`.

Comment: D'oh <slaps forehead>... yes, indeed. Always double check by testing.

Comment: @ypercube - answered as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(url) AS My_Count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY My_Count DESC 
LIMIT 10 ;
```